# How to filter Middleman articles by category

Tags: ruby, yaml, middleman

I have two blog types on the website. One is shown on one page and the other on the second page. How do I filter my category (or even better by blog)?

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.name = "cats"
  blog.prefix = "cats"
end

activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.name = "dogs"
  blog.prefix = "dogs"
end
```

Official docs say:

*This will create two blogs, one at /cats and one at /dogs. Notice that we give the blogs names. This is for helpers like a blog() - in order for them to know what blog we want, we can pass in the blog name to the blog helper like a blog('dogs'). In many situations, Middleman will automatically be able to find the right blog for helpers, but you may at times need to specify the blog name when using helpers like a blog, tag_path, etc. You can also specify the blog name in a page's frontmatter (such as in your tag page template) which will tell all helpers which blog to use.*

But when I input name: cats in my frontmatter I still get all results everywhere.

My layout code is this:

```
<body>
    <%= partial 'partials/header' %>
    <article>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns">
                <h1><%= current_page.data.title %></h1>
                <h2><%= current_page.data.subtitle %></h2>
                <%= yield %>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </article>
</body>
```

So, how do I use filter this on my layout?